# Multiple Django sites in Apache and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: django, apache

I'm currently trying to host 2 isolated Django web applications in one Apache instance. They work, however at random times a 500 HTTP error is raised.

Apache's logfile reveals that sometimes application A tries to load settings from application B, which means that the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE gets messed up between both applications.

I tried to run both sites embedded and in daemon mode, no success. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383176/

Comment: It is. Sorry, couldn't find that other question.

Comment: It seems the method below can solve your problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505576/deploying-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-with-mod-wsgi