# Multiple Django apps/projects on the same host

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505576/deploying-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-), in order to deploy multiple sites on Apache, do I need multiple Django projects (each of them with an app) or multiple apps in the same project?
Thanks, 
FB

Answer (score 0):

You can have different sites running off the same project, you should have different settings file for having different SITE_ID for different sites.