# Django with multiple sites in apache

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I have the following configuration in Apache web server for one site in a virtual environment and I am not using virtualhost...

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/mapsite
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mapsite/lib/python3.4/site-packages

WSGIScriptAlias /mapflat /var/www/mapsite/mapsite/wsgi.py
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}    
<Location "/mapflat">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Allow from all
AddHandler wsgi-script .py

</Location>
```

My question: if I were to have another site in another virtual environment  in future, do I append it to WSPythonHome with : or repeat the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully,This link should be helpful for you.

[Deploying multiple django apps on Apache with mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505576/deploying-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-with-mod-wsgi)

If it still doesn't help.Please comment.  :-)

---

**At your query regarding the executing mod_wsgi as a daemon mode-:**

It is for the sake of performance.
[Check here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process)

Kindly revert for more queries :-)

---

**At your query for windows.**

Thanks for asking

Daemons-
They are the processes which run in the background and are not interactive. They have no controlling terminal.

They perform certain actions at predefined times or in response to certain events. In *NIX, the names of daemons end in d.

In context of windows ,Daemonss becomes services.
So in context of windows,You need to install apache as a service.Detailed description is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#winsvc).

Process of implementation may be slightly different but actual intent is exactly same-The optimization.

cheers :-)

Comment: How about Django 1.7?

Comment: You will need to use : to seperate the different virtualenvironment paths of python.As also specified in this django documentation.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/.  Please let me know if you want to know more.

Comment: Do I need to run as a deamon?

Comment: It is recommended but not mandatory.Depends on your implementation and project requirements.If you are at learning stage,You should try both the ways but professionally definitely its always good to work with optimization.