# 2 Bitnami Django Projects Running at same time Apache WSGI

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, wsgi

I'm trying to set up 2 Django Projects within Apache using wsgi and I seem to be having trouble with the conf files for apache (which I know little about)

I have 2 projects ("MyTestProjOne" and "Project" - Naming I know :-/ )

If I restart the Apache Server and go to `[servername]/Project` first, it will start. However once I go to `[servername]/MyTestProjOne` it says `can not match url to Project.urls`
and it reverses.

All of these symptoms are due to a wsgi not running in daemon mode from what I've learned through google, however I dont' know how to fix it.

It is similar problem as this, however none of the solutions solved the issue as I can't run Daemon mode on a windows machine (from what I've been told).
[Deploying multiple django apps on Apache with mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505576/deploying-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-with-mod-wsgi)

my wsgi files are for project one ("MyTestProjOne") `wsgi.py`:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/MyTestProjOne')
os.environ.setdefault("PYTHON_EGG_CACHE", "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/MyTestProjOne/egg_cache")


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "MyTestProjOne.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and for Project 2 ("Project") `wsgi.py`:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "Project.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

my `httpd-app.conf` for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:8007>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.8/apache2/htdocs"
      <Directory "C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.8/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
      <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny                          
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3 >
  Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

# Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
Include "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/Project/conf/httpd-app.conf"
Include "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/MyTestProjOne/conf/httpd-app.conf""
</VirtualHost>
```

MyTestProjOne `httpd-app.conf`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /MyTestProjOne 'C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/MyTestProjOne/MyTestProjOne/wsgi.py'
<Directory "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/MyTestProjOne/MyTestProjOne">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>  
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/MyTestProjOne">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>

Alias /staticMyTestProjOne "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack Projects/MyTestProjOne/static"
```

Project `httpd-app.conf`:

```
Alias /static "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack Projects/Project/static"
WSGIScriptAlias /Project 'C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/Project/Project/wsgi.py'

<Directory "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/Project/Project">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>


<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>

</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Users/user/Bitnami Django Stack projects/Project">

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

You are forcing both applications to run in the same interpreter context, which Django doesn't support because of use of environment variables.

See related information in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html