# multiple django apps on a apache vhost where one is on root with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

similar to this:
[Deploying multiple django apps on Apache with mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505576/deploying-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-with-mod-wsgi)

I'm trying to host two django apps on mod_wsgi but one is on root. i.e. the WSGI directives would be

```
WSGIScriptAlias / <path to django wsgi file for app1>
WSGIScriptAlias /app2 <path to django wsgi file for app2>
```

Just using the WSGIScript aliases like this doesn't seem to work. I tried putting them in location directives but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

after Graham's answer below I attempted this:

```
<VirtualHost <server ip>:80>
    ServerName site1.com    

    ##### app2 CONFIG
    WSGIDaemonProcess app2 python-path=/<path to django app2>/:/<path to virtualenv app2>/ threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIProcessGroup app2

    WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /<path to app2 wsgi file>/


    ##### app1 CONFIG    
    WSGIDaemonProcess app1 python-path=/<path to django app1>/:/<path to virtualenv app1>/ threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIProcessGroup app1

    WSGIScriptAlias / /<path to app1 wsgi file>
</VirtualHost>
```

but unfortunately requests to site1.com/app2 still get handled by the django application app1. Did I make a mistake in the config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong order. Use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app2 <path to django wsgi file for app2>
WSGIScriptAlias / <path to django wsgi file for app1>
```

The most deeply nested must be first, else '/' will be matched first and override everything else.

---

UPDATE 1

After additions to question. Now use:

```
<VirtualHost <server ip>:80>
    ServerName site1.com    

    ##### app2 CONFIG
    WSGIDaemonProcess app2 python-path=/<path to django app2>/:/<path to virtualenv app2>/ threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

    <Location /app2>
    WSGIProcessGroup app2
    </Location>

    WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /<path to app2 wsgi file>/


    ##### app1 CONFIG    
    WSGIDaemonProcess app1 python-path=/<path to django app1>/:/<path to virtualenv app1>/ threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIProcessGroup app1

    WSGIScriptAlias / /<path to app1 wsgi file>
</VirtualHost>
```

You need to scope the `WSGIProcessGroup` directive to the sub URL so only that sub URL's requests are delegated to the mod_wsgi daemon process group.

Another way of writing above is:

```
<VirtualHost <server ip>:80>
    ServerName site1.com    

    ##### app2 CONFIG
    WSGIDaemonProcess app2 python-path=/<path to django app2>/:/<path to virtualenv app2>/ threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /<path to app2 wsgi file>/ process-group=app2

    ##### app1 CONFIG    
    WSGIDaemonProcess app1 python-path=/<path to django app1>/:/<path to virtualenv app1>/ threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIScriptAlias / /<path to app1 wsgi file> process-group=app1
</VirtualHost>
```

In other words, use the `process-group` option to `WSGIScriptAlias` to indicate where each should run.

When using daemon mode and only one application per process, also recommended to add:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

This forces use of main Python interpreter context by WSGI application in respective processes, avoiding problems that can arise where some Python packages with C extensions are not implemented correctly so as to work with Python sub interpreters.

Comment: ahh ok. so order is important. will attempt. thank you

Comment: i've updated my question based on this answer. Do you mind having a quick look and letting me know if i made a silly mistake? Thank you.